# What is this cryptic message from the movie “Leave the World Behind” (2023)?

Tags: analysis, leave-the-world-behind

What is this cryptic message in the film *Leave the World Behind* (2023)?

[image: Cryptic Message]

Comment: That the Post was hack3d? Or a trainee in charge of the keyboard?

Comment: Someone forgot to lock the cat out?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the message itself is supposed to have a specific meaning. It seems to be a visual effect to confirm the fact the there are hackers attacking critical infrastructure systems.

In the previous message we're informed that hackers attacked the power infrastructure, so this message is meant for us to understand they are also attacking the communication networks.